# XCTest: Is there a way to find a view of any type by ID in UI tests?

Tags: ios, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

In XCTest there's a way to get all UI elements by type, and then filter by accessibilityIdentifier like:

```
app.buttons[someID]
```

But what if I don't know the type of the view? If I'm looking for a UIView, I can write:

```
app.otherElements[someID]
```

but this excludes UIButton views.

I can implement this by calling [all the methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementtypequeryprovider) in succession (staticTexts, textViews, buttons, otherElements etc.), but something tells me it's not great in performance, because the list of types is huge.

Is there a generic method?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [descendants(matching:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1500791-descendants) to look for views of any type.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let element = app.descendants(matching: .any)["someID"]
```